# Customize the document library wizzard

Tags: document-library

I would like to ask, is it possible to add a custom field into the document library creation wizzard ?

Comment: Can you provide some more info about what are you trying to achieve? And also include SP version in your question (don't use tag).

Comment: You can create custom field for document library, but what do you mean by wizard in library creation???

Comment: @Paddy please only use answer if you really have a good answer. For clarification use comments

Answer (score 1):

There may be some valid cases where you need to offer a different experience when provisioning document libraries or sites.  If the out of the box process doesn't meet your needs, especially for a specific business case, you can always write a custom feature that can look and behave exactly the way you would like it to.

Here is the MSDN reference for the SPListCollection.Add() method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477358.aspx